# Mod-rewrite problems with REQUEST_FILENAME

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a problem with server interpreting domain.com/index as domain.com/index.php. This screws with my URL structure.

I have created a .htaccess file with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

So if I type in the URL domain.com/index/about I want to get index/about from `$_GET['url']`. But instead it is blank. If I type any other URL not starting with index, like domain.com/foo/bar I get the expected results.

I understand that this is due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` which ignores any Rewrite if a file with same filename exist.

So my RewriteRules gives me the results I want as long as URL doesn't involve the word index or other dir- or filename. And that is all fine, since I have no other dirs or files in the current dir.

**So question is;** Can I make it more specific, as to say ignore filename.php instead of just filename? Meaning that *domain.com/index/about* should work but not *domain.com/index.php/about*.

**Side question:** And why does *domain.com/index/about* not work anyways? I have no dir called index/about and no file called index/about. Why does it interpret index/something as index.php/something which makes no sense, as I cannot have a dir inside a file.